# Do JavaScript classes have a method equivalent to Python classes' __call__?

Tags: javascript, python

In Python, you can implement `__call__()` for a class such that calling an instance of the class itself executes the `__call__()` method.

```
class Example:
    def __call__(self):
        print("the __call__ method")

e = Example()
e() # "the __call__ method"
```

Do JavaScript classes have an equivalent method?

**Edit**

A summary answer incorporating the discussion here:

- Python and JavaScript objects are not similar enough for a *true* equivalent (prototype vs. class based, `self`, vs. `this`)
- The API *can* be achieved however using [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) or modifying the prototype – and maybe using `bind`?
- One should generally not do this: it is too far removed from the JS's structure and from the normal use of of JavaScript, potentially creating confusion among other JS devs, your future-self, and could result in idiosyncratic side-effects.

Comment: Not a huge fan of “don’t-do-this” on SO.  But. As a Python dev I tried to force JS to treat ‘this’ more like ‘self’ on my early JS code, using ‘bind’ or the like.  It works but I am now stuck with code that is un-JS in nature and hard to figure by a JS dev.  Not something I’ll repeat.  YMMV   As regards to __call__ I seem to recall a Design Pattern from the original book called Command, i.e. an object encapsulating a function.  Relevant in JS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I basically agree with @CertainPerformace that this isn't really something you would do in normal JS code. Having said that, proxies offer a lot of possibilities and you can create something that is surprisingly close to (on the surface) to Python's `__call__()`.

For example:

```js
class F extends Function{
    constructor(someID, arr, n){
        super()
        this.id = someID
        this.arr = arr
        this.n = n

        return new Proxy(this, {
            apply(target, thisArg, argumentsList) {
              return target.__call__(...argumentsList);
            }
        })
    }
    __call__(a){                  // simple mult functions
        return a * this.n
    }

    *[Symbol.iterator](){         // make it iterable for demo purposes
        yield *this.arr.map(this) // call itself in a map!
    }
}


let f = new F("FrankenFunction", [1, 2, 3, 4], 5)

// access instance variable
console.log("id:", f.id)

// call it 
console.log("calling with 100: ", f(100))

// use the iterator
// get multiples of calling this on arr
console.log([...f])

// change the __call__ function to power instead
F.prototype.__call__ = function(a){
    return  a ** this.n 
}
// change n to get squares:
f.n = 2

// call it again with new __call__
console.log("calling with 10:", f(10))  // 10**2
console.log([...f]) // or iterate
```

I really not sure if any of this is a good idea, but it's an interesting experiment.

Answer (score 5):

The only way to do this would be for the constructor to explicitly return a function, which can be called. (In Javascript, if you don't explicitly `return` inside a constructor, the newly created instance gets returned - but such an instance will be a plain object, not a function.)

```js
class Example {
  constructor() {
    return function() {
      console.log('function running');
    }
  }
}

const e = new Example();
e();
```

But this would be *really weird* to do, and would not allow you to reference any of the properties on the prototype, or anything like that. Better to avoid it, or to make a plain function that returns a function:

```js
const example = () => () => console.log('function running');
const e = example();
e();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get this done, but in a rather weird way.

There isn't anything like `__call__()`, `__add__()` or `__sub__()` in JavaScript - JavaScript does not support operator overloading.

However if you really want to make objects callable, you can do it by giving a function a different prototype:

```js
function createCallableObject(cls, fn) {
    // wrap the original function to avoid modifying it
    const wrapper = (...args) => fn(...args)
    // set the prototype of the wrapped function so we can call class methods
    Object.setPrototypeOf(wrapper, cls.prototype)
    return wrapper
}

class Example {
    method() { console.log('This is an instance of class Example') }
}
function example() { console.log('This is a function') }

const obj = createCallableObject(Example, example)
obj() // 'This is a function'
obj.method() // 'This is an instance of class Example'
console.log(obj.constructor) // 'class Example { ... }'
```